# powershell psobject getenumerator one

Tags: powershell

I borrowed some PowerShell code to compare hash table, and it returns a custom object with the name and difference indication of the hash entries. I want to output the difference returned.

The object:

```
 function result( [string]$side ) {
    if ($ReturnVals) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          'InputKey'= "$path$key";
          'SideIndicator' = $side;
          'ReferenceValue' = $refValue;
          'DifferenceValue' = $difValue;
        }
    }
    else {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
          'InputKey'= "$path$key";
          'SideIndicator' = $side;
        }
    }
  }
```

When working with the returned object, if it is Null or has more than one entry, everything is fine, GetEnumerator does what is needed and output is sorted into the files:

```
if ($comp -eq $Null) {
    write-host $d "No Differences"
    out-file -filepath $of -inputobject "`nNo Differences" -Encoding UTF8 -append
}
else {
    write-host $d "Differences"
    $comp.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -property InputKey |
                out-file -filepath $of -append -Encoding UTF8
}
```

If there is one difference, PowerShell throws an error as the object has no method GetEnumerator:

Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] doesn't contain a method named 'GetEnumerator'.

I tried to use .count to see if there is one difference, but I don't get a count with just one. I get a count with 2 or more.

Custom Objects are a little advanced for my PowerShell skills. Any suggestions on how to prevent the error for one item in the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like when `$comp` is one item, it is not an array. You need to "initialize" `$comp` as an empty array. I don't see where it's coming from in your code, but something like this ought to work:

```
#This creates an empty array
$comp = @()
$comp += $foo
```

Answer (score 2):

Get-Enumerator is an array method.  If the function only returns one object, you don't get an array so the method doesn't work.  This is normal and expected behaviour.

You can modify the function to always return an array, but that's kind of a non-standard approach. You want the function to behave like other cmdlets and functions as much as possible.  Better to force it into an array outside of the function, in your main script:

```
$comp = @(result)
```

Comment: right that works too, it was actually going to be my first answer, but then decided to just change the code he gave... any info on why always returning the value as an array is a non-standard approach? just curious

Comment: It's non-standard because it produces unexpected behavior. I'd expect to only get an array if multiple objects are returned because that's how every other cmdlet or function I can think of would work (IMHO).

Comment: But you are doing the same thing... always making sure it is an array, which isn't necessary when calling normal PS cmdlets. I would think it would be more standard to change it on the function level, since functions are meant to be reused, so it behaves the same way no matter how you call it. But I guess that is just my opinion

Comment: Actually, what I've done is not at all uncommon when using normal PS cmdlets. Can you name any get-* cmdlet that will retun an array of one object?

Answer (score 1):

Use the comma operator to always return the value as an array :

```
function result( [string]$side ) {
    if ($ReturnVals) {
        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'InputKey'= "$path$key";
            'SideIndicator' = $side;
            'ReferenceValue' = $refValue;
            'DifferenceValue' = $difValue;
        }
    }
    else {
        $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'InputKey'= "$path$key";
            'SideIndicator' = $side;
        }
    }
    return ,$obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are good answers. I'm going to have to try them out, see if I can understand why it worked and why it didn't.  I had worked out a brute force solution of looking at the item type from GetType and taking an action if it is a PSOBJECT or OBJECT. Transcript from two tests, with more than one item it is a System.Object, with only one it is a ...PSCustomObject.

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell Transcript Start
Start time: 20140221140133

2014-02-21 2:02:01 PM Reading File 1
2014-02-21 2:02:02 PM Loading File 1 to Dictionary
2014-02-21 2:02:28 PM Reading File 2
2014-02-21 2:02:29 PM Loading File 2 to Dictionary
2014-02-21 2:02:56 PM Lines Compare

   *** The value of comp variable is:  @{InputKey=REPT.CRW.ARC_DIR_LST; SideIndicator=<>} @{InputKey=AD.CRW.PRDHOT07Y05; SideIndicator=<>}
   *** The length of comp is:  2
   *** The type is:  System.Object[]

2014-02-21 2:02:56 PM Writing Lines Compare Report
2014-02-21 2:02:56 PM Differences
2014-02-21 2:02:56 PM Compare  Objects End
.....
2014-02-21 2:03:31 PM Reading File 1
2014-02-21 2:03:32 PM Loading File 1 to Dictionary
2014-02-21 2:03:58 PM Reading File 2
2014-02-21 2:03:59 PM Loading File 2 to Dictionary
2014-02-21 2:04:25 PM Lines Compare

   *** The value of comp variable is:  @{InputKey=AD.CRW.PRDHOT07Y05; SideIndicator=<>}
   *** The length of comp is: 
   *** The type is:  System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

2014-02-21 2:04:25 PM Writing Lines Compare Report
2014-02-21 2:04:25 PM Differences
2014-02-21 2:04:25 PM Compare  Objects End

Windows PowerShell Transcript End
End time: 20140221140438
**********************
```